# Java netbeans Constructor arguments mismatch.no suitable constructor found for multidata object

Tags: java

```
public class MyItemsDataObject extends MultidataObject
{
public MyItemsData data ;
public MyItemsDataObject(FileObject pf,MyItemsDataLoader loader) 
                                        throws DataObjectExistsException,IOException{


      super(pf,loader)
```

The error comes on this super pf line someone point out where I went wrong.thankyou

Comment: Is this the constructor you are trying to call? http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-loaders/org/openide/loaders/MultiDataObject.html#MultiDataObject-org.openide.filesystems.FileObject-org.openide.loaders.MultiFileLoader-

Comment: no.not really.My subclass as shown  extends multidataobject and the constructor is for the myitemsdata class which is to act as an Drag and drop starting.

Comment: what is a `multidataobject ` then ? we is it defined? please show the code.

Comment: super calls to parent class, so your parent class shall contain constructor taking two params. i.e. in MultidataObject class.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the super(pf,loader) So, 
You have to create the constructor in MultidataObject with 2 parameters.